# Sizeof Pointer to Array

Tags: c++, pointers

If I have an array declared like this:

```
int a[3][2];
```

then why is:

```
sizeof(a+0) == 8
```

whereas:

```
sizeof(a)   == 24
```

I don't understand how adding 0 to the pointer changes the `sizeof` output. Is there maybe some implicit type cast?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you add `0` to `a`, then `a` is first converted to a pointer value of type `int(*)[2]` (pointing to the first element of an array of type `int[3][2]`). Then `0` is added to that, which adds `0 * sizeof(int[2])` bytes to the address represented by that pointer value. Since that multiplication yields 0, it will yield  the same pointer value. Since it is a pointer, `sizeof(a+0)` yields the size of a pointer, which is 8 bytes on your box.

If you do `sizeof(a)`, there is no reason for the compiler to convert `a` to a pointer value (that makes only sense if you want to index elements or to do pointer arithmetic involving the address of the elements). So expression `a` stays being of an array type, and you get the size of `int[3][2]` instead the size of `int(*)[2]`. So, `3 * 2 * sizeof(int)` which on your box is 24 bytes.

Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Calling `sizeof(a+0)` is the same as doing `sizeof(a[0])`, which is taking the size of the first `int[2]` element in the array, so `sizeof(int)*2 = 8`.  It is not taking the sizeof a pointer.

Comment: @Remy I would appreciate if you would formulate that theory and post it as a paper

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB: `a[0]` is equivalent to `*(a+0)`, not `(a+0)`.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` tells you the size of the type of the expression. When you add `0` to `a`, the type becomes a pointer (8 bytes on 64-bit systems).