# sizeof operands get evaluated?

Tags: c++

AFAIK sizeof doesn't evaluate its operands it C++.

E.g.

```
int x = 0;
sizeof(x += 1); // value of x is not changed
```

But what does this mean?

```
int arr[5];
sizeof(arr+0); // here array is converted to pointer
```

Why does the arithmetic on array is applied here?

> (§ 5.3.3/4) The lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and
>   function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are not applied to the
>   operand of sizeof.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this any way? This is not defined behavour of C/C++ code.

Comment: @mtahmed: Also see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759126/sizeof-pointer-to-array/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The sizeof() operator is calculated at compile time. The expressions are **NOT** evaluated. It is the **type** of the expression that is calculated (at compile time) and then used by sizeof().

So in your first one:

```
sizeof( x += 1);
```

The type of x is int. The result of the += operator is still int. So the sizeof() is still the size of int.

In this:

```
sizeof(arr+0);
```

Here arr is an array and would have returned the size of the array (if used by itself). But the operator + causes the array to decay into a pointer. The result of the + operator on an array and an integer is a pointer. So here the sizeof() operator will return the sizeof a pointer.

> (§ 5.3.3/4) The lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are not applied to the operand of sizeof.

This means that:

```
std::cout << sizeof(arr);
       // would print sizeof(int)* 5 (because there is no conversion)
       // if sizeof() had behaved like a normal function there
       // would have been a conversion but as you pointed out that
       // does not apply.
```

But here:

```
std::cout << sizeof(arr + 5);
       // prints the sizeof(int*) because the result of the expression
       // is a pointer type (int*)
```

#### As a side note:

This is why

```
int x[0];
int const xSize = sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]);

// This works correctly even though x[0] is technically
// not valid if used in a real expression (but is valid here).
```

Comment: Oh interesting...so at compile-time, the sizeof() expressions are replaced by something else (some expression or value maybe?) and then executed at run-time to return the required value?

Comment: Replaced by a `size_t` (unsigned integral constant expression), to be precise.

Comment: In Standard C++, `int x[0];` is an error. The size must be greater than zero!

Comment: "if sizeof had behaved like a normal function there would have been a converstion" - not true, it could take parameter by reference.

Answer (score 6):

It isn’t. In an arithmetic expression, array names decay into pointers. That says nothing about performing the calculation itself. The type of `+` is deducible from the types of its operands, in this case pointer and integer, yielding the same result as `sizeof(int*)`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know much about this, but if as you say, sizeof doesn't evaluate its operand then it must just rely on the *type* of the expression it's used on. So I would guess that `arr` on its own has a different type to `arr+0`, and that's why it was used.