# Declaring an array of pointers to structures in C, but not allocating memory for structure until needed

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to allocate space for an array of `n` pointers to a struct named `base` in C. I don't want to allocate the space for a struct unless it is needed.

If more than `n` structs are required during a user session, then I'll `realloc` another set of n pointers.

Would you please tell me if this is the correct method of declaring them, excluding any reallocation?

One reason I'm asking is, that I don't understand why `printf("%d", sizeof(ptr[0]))` returns `sizeof(base)` before any memory has yet been allocated
for an instance of `base`.

Is it simply because it's a pointer to base and will occupy that much space?

I just wanted to make sure that I'm not allocating the space for `n` structs of base before any are needed.

```c
/* Global declaration */
struct base { ... };
struct base *ptr;

/* in main() */
ptr = calloc( n, sizeof ( char ) );

/* Function to return pointer to newly allocated struct base */
struct base *base_alloc( void )
{
    return ( struct base * ) malloc( sizeof ( struct base ) );
}

/* Within a function to create new base and populate it.*/
ptr[i] = base_alloc();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?: _The sizeof() operator is calculated at compile time. The expressions are NOT evaluated. It is the type of the expression that is calculated_. From: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7788508/1606345 ?

Comment: `sizeof x` gives you the amount of memory occupied by `x`

Comment: Why do you use the size of a `char` here: `...= calloc(n, sizeof( char ))`?

Comment: @alk Because I was wrong and must've misunderstood the book example I was using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will clear up a couple of things:

> I don't understand why printf("%d", sizeof(ptr[0])) returns sizeof(base) before any memory has yet been allocated for an instance of base.

That is because `sizeof` evaluates the number of bytes occupied by *an object of the type* of an expression *at compile time*. E.g. here the expression `ptr[0]` has type `struct base` so `sizeof` returns the number of bytes needed to represent a `struct base` object. This is unrelated to memory allocation.

As for the rest of your code:

- You want `ptr` to have type `struct base **`.
- You also don't want to use `calloc` because `NULL` pointers are not guaranteed to actually have all bits set to zero.
- Finally, there is no need to cast the value returned by `malloc`.

So in total:

```
/* Global declaration */
struct base { ... };
struct base **ptr;

/* in main() */
ptr = malloc( n * sizeof *ptr );
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
  ptr[i] = NULL;
}

/* Function to return pointer to newly allocated struct base */
struct base *base_alloc( void )
{
  return malloc( sizeof ( struct base ) );
}

/* Within a function to create new base and populate it.*/
ptr[i] = base_alloc();
```

Comment: There is no need to *cast* the value returned by malloc.

Comment: You know you can just suggest edits rather than leave comments, right?

Comment: @Peter, past a relatively low rep threshold, we just perform edits, and in fact *cannot* merely suggest them.  I think I am not unusual in being very hesitant to do that with others' answers.  Certainly one can easily observe that commenting instead is utterly routine.  Besides, I am inclined to think that comments are more informative than edits -- but that is not to say that the answer should go unedited by its OP.

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind explaining a bit why it's struct base **ptr rather than *ptr?

Comment: I learned this much anyway, it won't compile without the **ptr because it can't set the pointers to NULL.  I'm having trouble understanding the difference between this and stack memory struct base *ptr[n].

Comment: This link helped to understand thanks. https://dyclassroom.com/c/c-pointers-and-array-of-structures I was just being stupid.